# Normal Map Not Baking Properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I'm modeling a Gameboy and I want the Start/ Select/ Nintendo logo to be indented. I followed a couple tutorials to the letter, but all my normal maps end up blank without any detail. There aren't any modifiers on either my Hi-rez or Low-rez model I want baked. I attached an image of my settings and the normal map result

My steps were:

1. created a new 2K image w/ 32 bit float checked
2. created a new material and added the new normal map to the image texture
3. selected the Hi-rez THEN the Low-rez
4. Checked "Select to Active"

[image]

Comment: The high-poly and low-poly objects are both at the same spot and there is overlapping geometry, right? Is *boy.001*  the high-poly version? ("selected last = *active* object" only works in the viewport. The *active* object can be a different one if you select them in the outliner)

Comment: @Blunder I figured out the issue and it was so dumb. I had 4 materials on both models. Once I took them all off everything worked fine. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Oh, multiple materials on one object. A good point for the checklist. I'm glad you solved the problem.